# What is this rigging technique called?

Tags: rigging, bones

when it comes to character rigging in blender I often come across a rig that looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the bones look like paths or something. I am actually really interested in this kind of rigging and like to learn more about it, but I couldn't find any tutorial yet. Maybe because I don't know what to search for. Maybe there is a specific term for this kind of rigging?

Thanks in advance

Comment: These are the **custom bone shapes**. Check out these tutorials to learn how to create them: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6aRdurh30f0 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YyTp-B7FIYI

Comment: @PaulGonet,thanks a lot .. exactly what I was looking for :).